# Is the receipt of the Sacrament of Confirmation a requirement before receiving the Sacrament of Holy Matrimony?

Tags: catholicism, marriage, sacraments, confirmation

I'm contemplating of getting married. However, I haven't been confirmed yet.

I need to know if it's actual Catholic law or if it's simply tradition to receive Confirmation before getting married.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you spoken to the priest you would like to perform the marriage?

Comment: @KorvinStarmast, not yet, sadly. Was busy working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While it is not an absolute requirement that Catholics be confirmed before they are married in the Church, confirmation before marriage is something the Church strongly urges. The Code of Canon Law states:

> Catholics who have not yet received the sacrament of confirmation are
>   to receive it before being admitted to marriage if this can be done
>   without grave inconvenience. (CIC 1065)

http://www.vatican.va/archive/ENG1104/__P3W.HTM

Term

> GRAVE INCONVENIENCE

Definition

> In moral theology a sufficient reason to excuse a person from
>   fulfilling certain positive precepts of the Church, not of themselves
>   binding by the natural or revealed law. Also sufficient reason for
>   delaying or even not performing certain actions, otherwise obligatory,
>   provided there is a sincere desire to do so.